# It it possible to add a variable in a pandas method chain / pipe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to add a variable using something along the following lines:

```py
N = 10
pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": np.random.random(N)},
).assign(y = x * 0.5)
```

I'm aware that I can do something along the following lines:

```py
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": np.random.random(N)},
)

df.assign(y=df["x"] * 0.5)
```

But I would like to be able to do this within the same chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this within the same chain.

```
N = 10
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.random(N)})
    .assign(y=lambda d: d['x']*0.5)
)
```

Use `lambda some_name` as to the dataframe created or changed before the `.assign`, and keep chaining along. Like:

```
N = 10
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.random(N)})
    .assign(y=lambda d: d['x']*0.5)
    .assign(z=lambda d: d.y * 2)
    .assign(w=lambda d: d.z*0.5)
)
```

Comment: Isn't this chained calling of `assign()` creating multiple copies of the dataframe? I'd suggest to _at least_ put all successive columns into a _single call_ to assign, no?